# Time a single execution of a function using timeit

Tags: python, timeit

print function is called many times.I want to calculate function's time.I wrote codes,

```
import timeit

class UserClass:
    def callname(self):
        print("HiTom")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def test():
        user = UserClass()
        user.callname()

    test()
    mtime = timeit.timeit(lambda: test())
    print(mtime)
```

When I run the codes,"Hi Tom" is called many times.
I really cannot understand why such a thing happens.

I rewrote

```
mtime = timeit.timeit(test(), number=1)
```

but ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable error happens.How can I make my ideal system?What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? That's what timeit *does*, calls what you provide it many times to get an average execution time. What were you *expecting* to happen?

Comment: Not too familiar with Python, but how about `mtime = timeit.timeit(lambda: test(), number=1)`

Comment: Thanks for accepting. You can also upvote answers if they were helpful (click the little triangle above the 0 to the left of my answer). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to

1. pass a string to the `stmt` field, and
2. pass a `globals` dict in order for `timeit` to figure out where the `test` function comes from

```
>>> timeit.timeit("test()", number=1, globals=globals())
HiTom
3.45029984600842e-05
```